# 3D dataset to 3D Numpy array

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, render, numpy-ndarray

I would like to visualize a 3D dataset in the form of a tiff file using Jupiter Notebook and Ipyvolume. To do this, I want to convert my dataset into a 3D numpy array. so far, this has only worked for me with a 2D dataset. For that I used this:

```py
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

im = Image.open("dataset2D.tif")

imarray=np.array(im)
```

Can someone help me how to do this with a 3D dataset?

Comment: Show us the shape of your data block

Comment: Is this a greyscale tiff, and you're wanting the luminance values from the pixels to be your `z` axis? The exact way the `tiff` is saved changes the answer here.

Comment: Yes, that's the key question.  What are you expecting in the third dimension?  An RGB TIFF should come in 3D, where the 3rd dimension has length 3.  A mono TIFF will come in 2D.

Comment: my dataset is three-dimensional and z is the height. The shape is 100x120x200